# Updating a table with multiple values from a select statement where the date matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm having a problem updating a table and im sure its pretty straight forward but im going round and round in circles here.

Table 'table1' data I want to update is formatted as follows:

```
[Month]                    Figure
----------------------------------
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
```

Table 'data1' that contains the updated figures is formatted as follows:

```
[Month]                    Figure
----------------------------------
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 0.7212
2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 1.2351
```

The SQL I'm using and the error message is as follows.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.figure = (SELECT figure from data1)
FROM table1 t1 JOIN data1 d1
ON (t1.[month] = d1.[month])


Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Would i need a while loop to go through each row?

I wish the end result to be as follows:

```
[Month]                    Figure
----------------------------------
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 0.7212
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 1.0000
2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 1.2351
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `UPDATE FROM`syntax for this.

Have a look at the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)  and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

> FROM (table_source)
>
> Specifies that a table, view, or derived table source is used to
>   provide the criteria for the update operation

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.figure = data1.figure
FROM    t1
        INNER JOIN data1 ON data1.month = t1.month
```

Comment: @Lieven: thanks for the answer. It helped solve my problem: http://www.leniel.net/2011/08/update-select-sql-server-image-column.html

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi - now this is the first time I'm mentioned in a blog. I'm going to print this and put it above my bed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.figure = data1.figure 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN data1 d1
ON (t1.[month] = d1.[month])
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008:

```
MERGE INTO Table1
USING data1 AS D1
   ON Table1.my_Month = D1.my_Month
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE 
           SET Figure = D1.Figure;
```

Pre-SQL Server 2008:

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET Figure = (
                 SELECT D1.Figure
                   FROM data1 AS D1
                  WHERE Table1.my_Month = D1.my_Month
                )
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM data1 AS D1
                WHERE Table1.my_Month = D1.my_Month
              );
```

Note the `UPDATE..FROM` syntax is proprietary and can yield unpredictable results when a target row matches more than one source row.